# Holomorphic function and deritives

Tags: complex-analysis, primitive-roots, holomorphic-functions

Is it true that there exists a holomorphic function whose derivative is $1/(z^2-1)$? How to tackle problems like these?

Comment: Write it as a taylor series with help of the geometric series. Then integrate termwise.

Comment: In what domain?

Comment: In $\Bbb C$ i guess, since it is complex analysis? But it is not specified in this problem.

Comment: @menag Then what?

Comment: Alright, I got my answer, which is false. Can someone confirm that?

Comment: Do you know how to get an antiderivative of a taylorseries in the domain of convergence?

Yes I can confirm that.

Comment: @menag Yep. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\dfrac1{z^2-1}$ is holomorphic in the open unit disk and so has a primitive there.

The primitive is given explicitly by integrating the Taylor series:
$$
\int \frac1{z^2-1}
=-\int \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^{2n}
=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{2n+1}}{2n+1}
$$

Both series converge in the open unit disk.

There is no primitive on the whole complex plane because the function is not even defined on the whole complex plane.

Comment: Wait.. so you are saying that this statement is true?